# Сохранения данных в файл и последующие использование при каждом запуске программы

Tags: c#, вывод, ввод

Всем добрый день. Меня мучает вопрос. Вот в чем интересность, у меня есть N-количество textbox. Необходимо первый раз ввести информацию, она видимо должна сохраниться в некий файл, чтобы при последующем запуске программы мне не выскакивало сообщение о повторном вводе данных. (происходило считывание данных с файла) и продолжало работать. У меня получается только один раз надо ввести а последующим только читать из файла для входа.

Работаю я на C# и Visual studio 2015.

Comment: Просто проверяйте существует ли файл с помощью функции System.IO.File.Exists если существует, то читайте данные, если нет, то пишите данные. В чем сложность то? Или вам готовый код нужен?

Comment: Я просто в первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь и нет опыта работы с такими параметрами. Ну да было бы проще с готовым кодом.

Comment: Если вы собираетесь работать с файлами прежде всего стоит подумать о формате данных. Можно использовать готовый, можно свой. Все зависит от характера данных. Если это просто строки без переходов на новую строку, то циклом сформировать массив строк и записать его в файл с помощью System.IO.File.WriteAllLines. Считать ь можно с помощью функции RewdAllLines. А вообще рекомендую почитать о работе с файлами. Например, здесь пример чтения: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Comment: Формат данных самый простой строковый.

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать `Settings`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        string filename = @"C:\WriteLines.txt";


        if (File.Exists(filename) == true)
        {
            StreamReader s = File.OpenText(filename);

            if (s.BaseStream.Length != 0)
            {
                string read = null;
                while ((read = s.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(read);
                }
                s.Dispose();
            }
            else {
                s.Dispose();
                save();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            save();
        }
     }
    static void save()
    {
        // Example #1: Write an array of strings to a file.
        // Create a string array that consists of three lines.
        string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
        // WriteAllLines creates a file, writes a collection of strings to the file,
        // and then closes the file.  You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\WriteLines.txt", lines);
    }
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно читать? Почему не просто `File.ReadAllLines`?

Comment: А как например занести в файл со всех textbox? Если использовать 'File.ReadAllLines' для каждого textbox то записывается с последнего.